# Send and read firestore snapshots from Stateful Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

sent a file snapshot from profile_page to profile_reset_page The value can be read from profile_reset_page initstate as wideget.data['1_email']

profile_page:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, i){
              var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(width: 30,),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              data['2_name'] + " " + data['5_3_athlete'],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('profile reset', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.teal, side: BorderSide.none, shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context){
                                return profile_reset_page(data:data);
                              }
                          ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );

            });
      } else{
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
),
```

What I want is to read the value from outside the initstate.

```
class profile_reset_page extends StatefulWidget {

  final data;

  profile_reset_page({super.key, required this.data});
  @override
  State<profile_reset_page> createState() => _profile_reset_pageState();
}

class _profile_reset_pageState extends State<profile_reset_page> {

  ///Text editing controllers
  final nameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.data['1_email']);
```

However inside, you cannot read widget.data['1_email'] from within TextEditingController(). Below is the error code and how can I solve it?

> The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation) Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (Documentation) Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.

It can be solved in StatelessWidget, but I need to use StatefulWidget to use context.